# Unable to change timezone in Django -Dialogflow integration

Tags: django, timezone

I'm unable to change the timezone of the dates introduced on a form in a Django app, I want to send this data to Dialogflow and I need it to be in "Europe/Madrid" timezone instead of UCT. I've reading similar question but I still didn't manage to solve it so I would really appreciate if you can help me.

**settings.py**

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Madrid'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
```

**models.py**

```
class Response(models.Model):
    statement = models.ForeignKey(Statement, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    response = models.CharField(max_length=400)

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(
        default=timezone.now(),
        help_text='The date and time that this statement was created at.'
    )

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(
        default=timezone.now(),
        help_text='The date and time that this response was created at.'
    )
```

Comment: Did you import  -------- from django.utils import timezone

Comment: import datetime -- ---- 
from datetime import date

Comment: Yes, I have included django.utils import timezone. Do you know how can I get the date on my timezone from there?

Comment: Did you import the given packages in models.py and in views.py  ?

Comment: date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, null=True, blank=True) try this code

Answer (score 0):

What's the OS version your Django APP running with?
If it is running with Windows, you could make the changes as below easily & forcibly in 'settings.py', which will write the datetime object to database and present on frontend pages with the same TIME_ZONE. But it's not a good choice to conduct a global APP.

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

**TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Shanghai'**

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

**USE_TZ = False**
```

In the document https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#std:setting-TIME_ZONE
You could check the Note:

```
'Django cannot reliably use alternate time zones in a Windows environment. If you’re running Django on Windows, TIME_ZONE must be set to match the system time zone.'
```

---

## But this is my BP and recommendation:

1. Change the TIME_ZONE to your local time zone, and keep USE_TZ as True in 'setting.py':

   TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Shanghai'

   USE_I18N = True

   USE_L10N = True

   USE_TZ = True
2. This will write and store the datetime object as **UTC** to the backend database.
3. Then use *template tag* to convert the UTC time in your frontend template as such:

   ```
               <td> 
                   {% load tz %}
                   {% get_current_timezone as tz %}
                   {% timezone tz %}
                       {{ message.log_date | time:'H:i:s' }}
                   {% endtimezone %} 
               </td>
   ```

or use the *template filters* concisely:

```
                <td> 
                    {% load tz %}
                    {{ message.log_date | localtime | time:'H:i:s' }}
                </td>
```

4. You could check more details in the official doc: [Default time zone and current time zone](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/timezones/)

   When support for time zones is enabled, Django stores datetime information in UTC in the database, uses time-zone-aware datetime objects internally, and translates them to the end user’s time zone in templates and forms.